# I am not able to access ytdl-core functions with nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, ytdl

I'm building a youtube download with nestjs and ytdl-core, when I import it it's giving the following error

```
[Nest] 3876  - 01/17/2023, 10:55:06 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInfo')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInfo')
    at DawnloadService.create (C:\Users\azure\www\backend\youtube-dawnload\src\dawnload\dawnload.service.ts:10:10)
    at DawnloadController.create (C:\Users\azure\www\backend\youtube-dawnload\src\dawnload\dawnload.controller.ts:11:33)
    at C:\Users\azure\www\backend\youtube-dawnload\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at C:\Users\azure\www\backend\youtube-dawnload\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\Users\azure\www\backend\youtube-dawnload\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

every time I make a http dx delta call to this function, when I run it I get the error.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateDawnloadDto } from './dto/create-dawnload.dto';
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';
import fs from 'node:fs';

@Injectable()
export class DawnloadService {
  async create(createDawnloadDto: CreateDawnloadDto) {

    ytdl.getInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=har3c93pJe0");

    return createDawnloadDto.videoURL
  }
}
```

Comment: what's in dto file?

Answer (score 0):

[ytdl-core doesn't use a default export](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/lib/index.js#L24). You should use `import * as ytdl from 'ytdl-core'`